# Can the modal verb "can" be pronounced as /ŋ(k)/?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, modal-verbs, phonology, phonetics

Can the modal verb "can" be pronounced as /ŋ(k)/ ?

It may be the context of a following /k/, as in "we can **c**ome and see", but I have also notice it being reversed /ŋ(k)/.

Therefore, I'd like to know whether this is true, in phonetic terms, and how widespread it is. Some academic reference to this process would be clarifying.

For example, 5:12 'and you can come over' https://youtu.be/sriYmFBvOsE?t=312

Comment: What is your question? What do you mean by "revesed /ŋ/?" Please make sure you are asking a question. I hear what you are referring to in the video, but you haven't actually asked a question to be answered.

Comment: I think this is an interesting question, and much clearer after the edit. Wouldn't the /k/ you're hearing after the nasal just be the start of the following word "come", though? Rather than a reversal, I think it's more likely that the initial /k/ is simply elided...

Comment: What I hear (and do in my own casual speech in that phrase) is that the initial /k/ of "can" becomes a glottal stop, and the remainder of the word becomes a syllabic nasal that assimilates to the place of articulation of the following /k/, thus becoming [ŋ]. As @sumelic suggeted, the [k] you hear after the [ŋ] is simply the beginning of the next word ("come). I spent some of my formative years in Texas (where the video seems to be taking place), and the phrase in the video sounds natural to me.

Comment: @KatherineLockwood I do not think there's a glottal stop before the nasal,  but after it for the geminated/assimilated/non-released /k/. The sequence <we can> /wiŋk̚ kən/ in IPA notation.

Comment: Sounds like perfectly idiomatic speech to me -- not even much of a southern drawl.  The sentence "So we can come and see" is spoken rapidly, with the words slightly run together.  And "can" comes out closer to "ken", plus the sentence is aborted after "see", when the speaker switches to giving camera directions mid-sentence.

Comment: @KatherineLockwood, That's also how I say it (I'm from Ohio originally); but the phonological development is (1) progressive assimilaton of [kn] to [kŋ], then [k] becomes glottal stop before the following homorganic stop.  Similarly, my pronunciation of "hypnotize" has glottal stop + [m], by first progressive assimilation of place, then [p] becoming glottal stop before homorganic [m],

Comment: @GregLee ... interesting. I tried out "we can ___ now" with a variety of verbs, but only got the [ʔŋ] output when the next word started with k or g.

Comment: @KatherineLockwood, And not in "bacon" [bejʔŋ]?  Then maybe you don't have the progressive place assimilation process that I have.

Comment: Perhaps the technical term that fits this best is glottal reinforcement

Comment: The key would be to know how youtube close captions are automatically generated

Comment: @KatherineLockwood could you, please, upload your pronounciation of those different sentences with different verbs?

Comment: @GregLee  could you, please, upload your pronunciation of those different sentences with different verbs? including _hypnotize_

Comment: @GJC, No, I'm not set up here to make audio files.  The details are: (1) syllable offset voiceless stops are glottalized before stops -- meaning that they are pronounced with closure of the glottis (they are not ejective). (2) alveolar stops (t/d/n) assimilate in position regressively to a stop.  (3) In a homorganic stop cluster, the oral articulation can be delayed, leaving behind just a glottal stop, in the case of consonants that were glottalized in step (1),  For instance in "pop bottle", /pb/ >(1) [p'b] >(3) [ʔb], and in "hot mama", /tm/ >(1) [t'm] >(2) [p'm] >(3) [ʔm].

Comment: The video is not available on youtube. Can you repost it?

Comment: To clarify: you've used the notation for *phonemic* transcription, /.../; but it sounds like you're actually interested in a *phonetic* realization of <can> as [ŋ(k)]?

Comment: @Mitch try 5:12 'and you can come over' https://youtu.be/sriYmFBvOsE?t=312

Comment: @GJC OK, now listening to it "you can come over" there, I think I hear what you are hearing. I (as a native speaker) process it as /'ju: ŋ'kʌm 'ou vr/ I would pronounce it only slightly differently as /'ju: kn'kʌm 'ou vr/. I wouldn't call it might be a natural sound change, to go from /kn/ to /ŋ/ (assimilation of the nasal to a velar before a velar plus metathesis, just 'mushing everything together' I think is the technical term for it.

Comment: Which is to say, I don't really feel like you would want to intentionally use /ŋ/ for 'can' before a velar like in 'can come'. In faster inarticulate speech, where things get 'mushed together', maybe such assimilation can happen, but it is not mandatory.

Comment: @Mitch It appears also before a **/t/**: _We can tell_ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9y_uAv_kJUs

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it exists but more prominently when the modal, preposition or any word is unstressed and takes a schwa sound (ə). It has the ability to transform to [ŋ] as a bridge to the K in the next word. This is because there is resistance to articulate the consonant n if your following word is more strongly stressed (a nasal is a closer bridge to a glottal stop and the schwa sound invites it for linking purposes). . If you stress the modal 'can' [kæn] the [ŋ] disappears. I notice the same effect with unstressed prepositions eg "in Canada." and relative pronouns eg "when crying...".

Comment: This is because the effects of regressive assimilation (the upcoming [k] changing the previous nasal to [ŋ]) are more notable in the reduced unstressed syllables of connected speech, and less noticeable when carefully separated out through emphasis.

Comment: It appears also before a **/t/**: _We can tell_ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9y_uAv_kJUs